# Getting Telegram bio via Java Script

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

**How Can I get users `bio` in New telegram feature?**

Same as This Bot:(https://telegram.me/getidsbot)

[image: Photo]

I'm using This Module: (https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api)

I Don't know how this bot getting my bio!!!??? Because It is not added to the bot api yet, is there a magic way??

Comment: It doesn't look implemented yet: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user

Comment: I Can See in This Bot: (https://telegram.me/getidsbot)

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei that bot is likely using the Telegram API (not to confused with the Telegram Bot API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
You can fetch the page and extract the bio from the html content!
`https://t.me/<username> (Replace <username>)`